# Помогите сформировать массив

Tags: php

Подскажите как правильно сравнить и вывести в массив данные из БД.

Как сравнить поля $category['category_id'] и $category['parent_id'] и если они совпадают то добавить их в массив $child.

Уже есть вот такой массив:

```
[62] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 62
        [image] => 
        [parent_id] => 0
        [top] => 1
        [column] => 1
        [sort_order] => 0
        [status] => 1
        [date_added] => 2020-05-23 13:47:51
        [date_modified] => 2020-05-23 14:47:26
        [language_id] => 1
        [name] => Металлопрокат
        [description] => 
        [meta_title] => 
        [meta_h1] => 
        [meta_description] => 
        [meta_keyword] => 
        [store_id] => 0
        [href] => http://test.bbden.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=62
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [63] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 63
                        [image] => 
                        [parent_id] => 62
                        [top] => 0
                        [column] => 1
                        [sort_order] => 0
                        [status] => 1
                        [date_added] => 2020-05-23 13:48:32
                        [date_modified] => 2020-05-23 13:48:32
                        [language_id] => 1
                        [name] => Труба металическая
                        [description] => 
                        [meta_title] => 
                        [meta_h1] => 
                        [meta_description] => 
                        [meta_keyword] => 
                        [store_id] => 0
                        [href] => http://test.bbden.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=63
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                                [64] => Array
                                    (
                                        [category_id] => 64
                                        [image] => 
                                        [parent_id] => 63
                                        [top] => 0
                                        [column] => 1
                                        [sort_order] => 0
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [date_added] => 2020-05-23 13:48:58
                                        [date_modified] => 2020-05-23 13:49:12
                                        [language_id] => 1
                                        [name] => Труба электросварная
                                        [description] => 
                                        [meta_title] => 
                                        [meta_h1] => 
                                        [meta_description] => 
                                        [meta_keyword] => 
                                        [store_id] => 0
                                        [href] => http://test.bbden.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=64
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Получаю его так:

```
     class ControllerExtensionModuleCategorywallhome extends Controller {

          protected function debug($data){
            echo '<pre>'. print_r($data, true) .'</pre>';
          }

          public function index() {
            $this->load->language('extension/module/categorywallhome');

            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
              $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
            } else {
              $parts = array();
            }

            if (!empty($parts)) {
              $data['active'] = end($parts);
            }else{
              $data['active'] = 0;
            }


            $this->load->model('catalog/categorywallhome');

            $data['categories'] = array();

            $categories = $this->model_catalog_categorywallhome->getwallCategories();

            foreach($categories as $id => $category){
              $categories[$id]['href'] =  $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id']);
            }
            $data['categories_tree'] = $categories = $this->model_catalog_categorywallhome->getMapTree($categories);
            $this->debug($categories);


            return $this->load->view('extension/module/categorywallhome', $data);
          }
        }

    Сам запрос в БД :
class ModelCatalogCategorywallhome extends Model {
  public function getwallCategories() {
    $query = $this->db->query(
      "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c 
      LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
      LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) 
      WHERE cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'  AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)");

    $cats = [];
    foreach($query->rows as $row){
      $cats[$row['category_id']] = $row;
    }
    return $cats;
  }
  public function getMapTree($dataset){
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($dataset as $id => &$node) {
      if (!$node['parent_id']) {
        $tree[$id] = &$node;
      }else{
        $dataset[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
      }
    }
    return $tree;
  }
}
```

На выходе нужно получить такой массив только с потомками в children:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 62
            [name] => Металлопрокат
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

            [href] => http://test.bbden.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=62
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 59
            [name] => Пиломатериалы
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

            [href] => http://test.bbden.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=59
        )
```

Comment: Очень сложно читать Ваш код. Понимаю, что не по теме, но попробуйте произвести его декомпозицию - сильно поможет и сейчас и в будущем. PS: и замените котов на категории))